# PHP Contact Form with only one letter

Tags: php, forms

I've got a phpmailer form set up, and it sends fine. But when it gets to the email address it's going to, only the first letter of the message sent shows. For example, if I put 'Test message from the contact for' all that would come through to the email is the below:

Name: Tom 
Email: tom@hotmail.com 
Phone: 
Subject: Test 2 
Message: T 
Monday, 27 February 2017 , 14:20:48

I've tried looking at the code but not being that knowledgeable in PHP, cant see a problem.

Can anyone help me out here?

**This is the form**

```
<form action="php/contact.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <fieldset>
                                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="contact_send" />

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <label for="contact:name">Full Name *</label>
                                            <input required type="text" value="" class="form-control" name="contact[name][required]" id="contact:name">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <label for="contact:email">E-mail Address *</label>
                                            <input required type="email" value="" class="form-control" name="contact[email][required]" id="contact:email">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <label for="contact:phone">Phone</label>
                                            <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" name="contact[phone]" id="contact:phone">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <label for="contact:subject">Subject *</label>
                                            <input required type="text" value="" class="form-control" name="contact[subject][required]" id="contact:subject">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <label for="contact:message">Message *</label>
                                            <textarea required maxlength="10000" rows="8" class="form-control" name="contact[message]" id="contact:message"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> SEND MESSAGE</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

**This is the contact.php**

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
@ini_set('display_errors', 0);
@ini_set('track_errors', 0);

require('config.inc.php');



if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'contact_send') {
    $email_body = null;
    $array      = $required = array();


    $post_data  = isset($_POST['contact']) ? $_POST['contact'] : null;
    $is_ajax    = (isset($_POST['is_ajax']) && $_POST['is_ajax'] == 'true') ? true : false;


    if($post_data === null) {
        if($is_ajax === false) {
            _redirect('#alert_mandatory');
        } else {
            die('_mandatory_');
        }
    }


    foreach($post_data as $key=>$value) {
        $key_title = ucfirst($key);


        $explode = @explode('_', $key_title);
        if(!isset($explode[1]))
            $explode = @explode('-', $key_title);

        if(isset($explode[1])) {
            $key_title = implode(' ', $explode);
            $key_title = ucwords(strtolower($key_title));
        }



        if(isset($post_data[$key]['required'])) {
            $required[] = $key;


            if($key == 'name')
                $array['name'] = $post_data[$key]['required'];

            if($key == 'email')
                $array['email'] = $post_data[$key]['required'];


            $email_body .= "<b>{$key_title}:</b> {$post_data[$key]['required']} <br>";



        } else {
            $non_required[] = $key;


            if($key == 'name')
                $array['name'] = $post_data[$key];

            if($key == 'email')
                $array['email'] = $post_data[$key];


            $email_body .= "<b>{$key_title}:</b> {$post_data[$key]} <br>";
        }


    }




    foreach($required as $req) {
        if(strlen(trim($post_data[$req]['required'])) < 1)  { // changed from 2 to 1 [11:47 AM Saturday, June 18, 2016]
            if($is_ajax === false) {
                _redirect('#alert_mandatory');
                exit;
            } else {
                die('_mandatory_');
            }
        }
    }





    $array['email'] = ckmail($array['email']);
    if($array['email'] === false) {
        if($is_ajax === false) {
            _redirect('#alert_mandatory');
            exit;
        } else {
            die('_mandatory_');
        }
    }










    $ip = ip();



    $date        = date('l, d F Y , H:i:s');
    $email_body .= "{$date} <br>";





    if($config['use_smtp'] === true) {

        require('phpmailer/5.2.10/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
        require('phpmailer/5.2.10/class.phpmailer.php');


        $m = new PHPMailer();
        $m->IsSMTP();
        $m->SMTPDebug   = false;                    // enables SMTP debug information (for testing) [default: 2]
        $m->SMTPAuth    = true;                     // enable SMTP authentication
        $m->Host        = $config['smtp_host'];     // sets the SMTP server
        $m->Port        = $config['smtp_port'];     // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
        $m->Username    = $config['smtp_user'];     // SMTP account username
        $m->Password    = $config['smtp_pass'];     // SMTP account password
        $m->SingleTo    = true;
        $m->CharSet     = "UTF-8";
        $m->Subject     = $config['subject'];
        $m->AltBody     = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!';

        $m->AddAddress($config['send_to'], $config['subject']);
        $m->AddReplyTo($array['email'],   isset($array['name']) ? $array['name'] : $array['email']);
        $m->SetFrom($config['smtp_user'], isset($array['name']) ? $array['name'] : $array['email']);
        $m->MsgHTML("
            {$email_body}
            ---------------------------------------------------<br>
            IP: {$ip}
        ");

        if($config['smtp_ssl'] === true)
            $m->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                 


        if($m->Send()) {
            // die('sent');
            if($is_ajax === false) {
                _redirect('#alert_success');
                exit;
            } else {
                die('_success_');
            }
        } else {

            if($is_ajax === false) {
                _redirect('#alert_failed');
                exit;
            } else {
                die('_failed_');
            }
        }



    } else {


        mail( 
            $config['send_to'] , 
            $config['subject'],
            $email_body
        );

        if($is_ajax === false) {
            _redirect('#alert_success');
            exit;
        } else {
            die('_success_');
        }
    }


    exit;
}


function _redirect($hash) {

    $HTTP_REFERER = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : null;

    if($HTTP_REFERER === null)
        die("Invalid Referer. Output Message: {$hash}");

    header("Location: {$HTTP_REFERER}{$hash}");
    exit;
}


function ckmail($email) {
    $email = trim(strtolower($email));
    if(preg_match('/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/',trim($email))){
        return $email;
    } else { return false; }
}


function ip() {
    if     (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))       { $ip = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');       } 
    elseif (getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')) { $ip = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'); } 
    elseif (getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))     { $ip = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');     } 
    elseif (getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))   { $ip = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');   } 
    elseif (getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))       { $ip = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');       } 
                                       else { $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];        } 
    return $ip;
}
```

?>

Comment: Can you post the code which you're sending the mail?

Comment: POst your code, so we know where you went wrong

Comment: You should consider adding your code it will help us help you. Please read the [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make sure to ask a well construct and answerable question.

Comment: Sorry just trying to work out how to post code it keeps saying too long

Comment: @Walruss paste your code

Comment: Added code to original post, thank you.

Comment: echo $email_body = $date. "<br>";  check befor send email what is in email body